# Theme changer on body load is not working using radio button state selection and onload selected?

Tags: jquery, radio-button, checked

I have created a theme changer using simple radio button i want when the radio button state checked, then that theme should be selected and working.

**Below is the code**

***for local storage selection.***

```
$(function(){
$('input[type=radio]').each(function(){
    var state = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('radio_'  + $(this).attr('value')) );
    if (state) this.checked = state.checked;
}); }); $(window).bind('unload', function(){
$('input[type=radio]').each(function(){
    localStorage.setItem('radio_' + $(this).attr('value'), JSON.stringify({checked: this.checked})
    );
});
```

});

***Radio button code ***

```
$("input[name$='sidebarccolor']").click(function () {
   var radio_theme = $(this).val();
    if (radio_theme == 'default') {
        $('link[href="css/style.css"]').attr('href','css/style.css');
        $('link[href="css/stylered.css"]').attr('href','css/style.css');
        $('link[href="css/stylegreen.css"]').attr('href','css/style.css');  
         $('link[href="css/styleblue.css"]').attr('href','css/style.css');
      }
    else if (radio_theme == 'red') {
      $('link[href="css/style.css"]').attr('href','css/stylered.css');
        $('link[href="css/stylered.css"]').attr('href','css/stylered.css');
        $('link[href="css/stylegreen.css"]').attr('href','css/stylered.css');   
         $('link[href="css/styleblue.css"]').attr('href','css/stylered.css');
     }
     else if (radio_theme == 'green') {
       $('link[href="css/style.css"]').attr('href','css/stylegreen.css');
        $('link[href="css/stylered.css"]').attr('href','css/stylegreen.css');
        $('link[href="css/stylegreen.css"]').attr('href','css/stylegreen.css'); 
         $('link[href="css/styleblue.css"]').attr('href','css/stylegreen.css');
     }
     else if (radio_theme == 'blue') {
       $('link[href="css/style.css"]').attr('href','css/styleblue.css');
        $('link[href="css/stylered.css"]').attr('href','css/styleblue.css');
        $('link[href="css/stylegreen.css"]').attr('href','css/styleblue.css');  
         $('link[href="css/styleblue.css"]').attr('href','css/styleblue.css');
     } });
```

Selected state is already working (it means radio button selection working fine on body onload ). But I can`t get selected radio themes on body load.

Comment: This question is totally different mark please read the question again

Comment: no, Basically I have create a style sheet changer and using radio button but on body load style sheet change only work on click not applied on body load.

Comment: How do you send the initial value for the `onload`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer

```
    //choose themes color changer
    $("input[name$='sidebarccolor']").click(function () {
       var radio_theme = $(this).val();
        if (radio_theme == 'default') {
            $('link[href="css/style.css"]').attr('href','css/style.css');
            $('link[href="css/stylered.css"]').attr('href','css/style.css');
            $('link[href="css/stylegreen.css"]').attr('href','css/style.css');  
             $('link[href="css/styleblue.css"]').attr('href','css/style.css');
          }
        else if (radio_theme == 'red') {
          $('link[href="css/style.css"]').attr('href','css/stylered.css');
            $('link[href="css/stylered.css"]').attr('href','css/stylered.css');
            $('link[href="css/stylegreen.css"]').attr('href','css/stylered.css');   
             $('link[href="css/styleblue.css"]').attr('href','css/stylered.css');
         }
         else if (radio_theme == 'green') {
           $('link[href="css/style.css"]').attr('href','css/stylegreen.css');
            $('link[href="css/stylered.css"]').attr('href','css/stylegreen.css');
            $('link[href="css/stylegreen.css"]').attr('href','css/stylegreen.css'); 
             $('link[href="css/styleblue.css"]').attr('href','css/stylegreen.css');
         }
         else if (radio_theme == 'blue') {
           $('link[href="css/style.css"]').attr('href','css/styleblue.css');
            $('link[href="css/stylered.css"]').attr('href','css/styleblue.css');
            $('link[href="css/stylegreen.css"]').attr('href','css/styleblue.css');  
             $('link[href="css/styleblue.css"]').attr('href','css/styleblue.css');
         } });

//used for local storage.
$(function(){
    $('input[type=radio]').each(function(){
        var state = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('radio_'  + $(this).attr('value')) );
        if (state) this.checked = state.checked;


    });
});
$(window).bind('unload', function(){
    $('input[type=radio]').each(function(){
      localStorage.setItem('radio_' + $(this).attr('value'), JSON.stringify({checked: this.checked}));
        //$(this).trigger("click");
    });

}); 
setTimeout(function(){ 
          $('input[type=radio]:checked').removeProp("checked");  
          $('input[type=radio]:checked').attr("checked", true).trigger("click");
 });
```